# Excel formula to find the average of bottom 25% from the selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, quartile

I have numbers in one column (A1:A100),
is there a function to find the average from values that are over 75% ?

For example: = average(A76:A100)

I first thought that =quartile(A1:A100;3) will do the job, but this is a bit different.

In real situation I have much more rows (A1:A41535).

Comment: Or perhaps you mean `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A100,">="&QUARTILE.INC(A1:A100,3))`?

Comment: Jos Woolley, this was exectly what I was looking for. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your consideration:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=AVERAGE(TAKE(A1:A6,-(COUNT(A1:A6)/4)))
```

Or, more dynamic:

```
=LET(r,A1:A6,AVERAGE(TAKE(r,-(COUNT(r)/4))))
```

Or, even more dynamic:

```
=LET(r,TOCOL(A:A,3),AVERAGE(TAKE(r,-ROUNDUP(COUNT(r)/4,0))))
```

The latter would take any amount of numbers in column A:A.

Comment: Thank you! I guess all your solutions work but I have Excel 2019 and it seems that there is no TAKE function :D

Comment: Be aware that you shouldn't accept answers that don't work =) @fred I'll see if I can edit in an Excel 2019 answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it earlier that i am using Excel 2019. Strange that it receives updates but new functions are not coming.

Comment: These functions are for ms365 @fred, not 2019. If you want access to these functions you'd need to buy 365 or use Excel Web

Comment: @fred, please check `=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A:A)>(COUNT(A:A)/4)*3)*(A:A))/CEILING(COUNT(A:A)/4,1)` to see if that works for your Excel. It may be a bit slow.

Comment: At first it seemed to be working, but when I use it for selection, it does not work.
Please see the picture: https://imgur.com/a/lOCvtYL

Comment: That's because that formula will evaluate each input's rownumber against a count. So you'd need to deduct the starting row and add 1. Something along these lines: `=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A10:A15)-ROW(A10)+1>(COUNT(A10:A15)/4)*3)*(A10:A15))/CEILING(COUNT(A10:A15)/4,1)` @fred

Comment: @JvdV maybe I am missing something, but to exclude the first 25% we would need to use `DROP`. In a way it is formulated using `TAKE` it will take the last 25% from the input range (`r`).

Comment: @DavidLeal, I used a negative number for the 2nd parameter in `TAKE()` to take only the last few rows of data. It's just the opposite of `DROP()` however I suppose one can re-formulate the answer above to fit in this function too.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`=AVERAGEIF(A1:A100,">="&QUARTILE.INC(A1:A100,3))`

Comment: I played with this formula and I think it still does not work as I want.
For example, if I have numbers in one column:
9
1
1
2
2
2

The formula gives = 3.75
But it should be 2, because I want the average last 25% of values. These are temperature measurements and I want the average of 25% last measurements.

Comment: I think the reason is because Quartile internally finds the value of the range sorted, so the `AVERAGEIF` condition will return all values greater or equal than `2` (`{2;2;2;9}`) and the average requested is from the last 25% elements of the range (which is not sorted) and therefore only the last value should be considered from the list. Basically Quartile is for a different purpose and also to take into consideration that Quartile does extrapolation.